# What should be the behavior when malformed udp packets are received in RTPStream

Tags: webrtc

Is there any standard that defines the behavior when malformed UDP packets(like UDP packets with empty payload) is received in RTPStream?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. Malformed packets are largely left ignored, as the assumption is that all is well with the world.

In most cases, there's one of three different behaviors you should be expecting - depending on how things got implemented:

1. Browser crash. In such a case, just file a bug with the browser vendor
2. Ignore. The browser will ignore the packet altogether and move on
3. Disconnect. The browser may decide to disconnect the peer connection due to that (highly unlikely, but not unheard of)

Just don't send malformed packets on a media connection and expect  consistent behavior.